# How to increase performance on manipulating large arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, heap-memory, java-io

I am solving a problem on Hackerrank right now and I believe my logic is more or less correct, but the larger datasets are slowing down the performance so as to give me a "wrong" answer. Here is a link to the problem so you can check it out:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/qheap1

I am wondering how to increase the performance of this script so as to allow for larger datasets. I have a hunch it has to do with the Scanner, but I don't know why.

```
public class Solution {
    private static final int ADD = 1;
    private static final int DELETE = 2;
    private static final int GET = 3;
    private static final int TICK = 1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintStream out = System.out;
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] heap = new int[n];

        int a = 0;
        while (a < n) {
            a = 0;
            int q = in.nextInt();

            switch(q) {
                case(ADD):
                    int nextAdd = in.nextInt();
                    /*out.println("ADD " + next);*/
                    int b = 0;
                    while (b < n) {
                        /*out.println(heap[b]);*/
                        if (heap[b] == 0) {
                            heap[b] = nextAdd+TICK;
                            /*printArray(heap);*/
                            b = n-1;
                        }
                        b++;
                    }
                    /*printArray(heap);*/
                    break;
                case(DELETE):
                    int c = 0;
                    int nextDelete = in.nextInt();
                    while (c < n) {
                        if (heap[c]-TICK == nextDelete) {
                            heap[c] = 0;
                            c = n-1;
                        }
                        c++;
                    }
                    /*printArray(heap);*/
                    break;
                case(GET):  
                    Arrays.sort(heap);
                    int d = 0;
                    while (d < n) {
                        if (heap[d] != 0) {
                            out.println(heap[d]-TICK);
                            d = n-1;
                        }
                        d++;
                    }
                    /*printArray(heap);*/
                    break;
            }
            a++;
            /*printArray(heap);*/
        }
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] ar) {
        String str = "";
        for (int i : ar) {
            str += i + " ";
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: for "working" code you might turn to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: In general: you might want to work on **readability** first. I have a really hard time figuring what your code is doing. It would be helpful for example if you would push your switch cases into individual methods (with good names for methods and variables). It is **hard** to solve such performance things just from looking at code, and if that code is written in that hard-to-read way, things dont get easier.

Comment: It's hapenning because your alghoritm just has a quadratic complexity, i.e. on each iteration by `a` you traverse all the heap. Meaning you'll do `n` iteration on `a`, and each of those will do another `n` iterations (via `b`, `c` or `d`, for `d` you'll do even more - `n*logn`). It could be improved by implementing a correct data-structure for your purpose as suggested by @Lashane. Have a look at the source-code of `PriorityQueue` - it's built over an array as well, but applies special ordering of elements so you can skip big portions of elements and therefore increasing the speed.

Comment: Which source code?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, the only *immediate* problem that I can spot is the fact that this line

```
out.println(heap[d]-TICK);
```

isn't commented out. That could mean that your java program (no, it is not a *script*, mind your wording!) is doing a lot of IO operations. And those are very **expensive** compared to anything else going on in your program.

So, comment that out and see what happens then.

Comment: I see, yes, that makes sense. Okay, I just tried to run the program with a different output process, i.e. instead of doing `out.println(heap[d]-TICK)`, I initialized a static, empty String `HEAP` and added to it `HEAP += Integer.valueOf(heap[d] - TICK).toString() + "<br>";`. That way, after the bulk of the input was finished, I could merely split that String and print each number. However, I ran into the same performance issues as before. In theory, I think that may be a decent process, though.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your approach that you don't use heap (as it is required by challenge), you're spending too much time working with array.

Here is the implementation which passes all tests:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    final int n = in.nextInt();
    final PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<>(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        final int command = in.nextInt();
        switch (command) {
        case 1:
            q.add(in.nextInt());
            break;
        case 2:
            q.remove(in.nextInt());
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println(q.peek());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the correct answer; but I am still wondering if somebody who tries to resolve such a "hacking" thing is really interested in just getting the "full" answer. You know, what is the point of "solving" a puzzle by receiving the complete solution by other people ... when you asked for "help to solve" ...

Comment: @GhostCat I doubt that it is a hacking or puzzle, just simple algorithmic exercise, unless you're using proper data structure - you will not be able to pass all tests

Comment: @Lashane, I don't know why, but I am inclined to solve every puzzle on Hackerrank with Arrays. I definitely see the appeal of using something from the Collections Framework (given the elegant solution you provided), and as a professional, I think it is wise to do so, but I am still curious about performance in this case.

Comment: @PeterWard priority query is part of standard JDK. you can solve this problem with arrays, but you have to implement priority queue first